# How can I know if a TableView is empty?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to do a BooleanBinding in JavaFX 8 that determinates if a TableView is empty. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
Bindings.isEmpty(table.getItems())
```

Comment: this is _the_ answer :) just a minor note: technically, getItems can return null which would throw in the binding

Answer (score 0):

```
ObservableList<> items = table.getItems();

if (items.isEmpty()) {
     //do some
} else {
     //your table wasn't empty
}
```

Should also work

Comment: the question was about using BooleanBinding with lists emptyness - so this is not an answer to the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

the code bellow work for me
try it ! it's very simple

```
ObservableList<> list = tableview.getItems();

if (list.size() > 0) 
{

} 
else 
{
     //Empty Tableview
}
```

Comment: It is always better to use `isEmpty` rather than `size` if you only care about empty/non-empty, as some implementations (e.g. `LinkedList`) could have non-trivial complexity for `size`.

Comment: the question was about using BooleanBinding with lists emptyness - so this is not an answer to the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    //import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
    if(Bindings.isEmpty(tableViewFxId.getItems()).get()) {
        //EMPTY


    }else{
        //FILLED


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a `TableView` must be populated from an `ObservableList`, the simplest way to check if the table is empty, is to check if the `ObservableList` is empty.

```
if (yourObservableList.isEmpty(){
    // run code if table is empty.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or Try This:

```
package application;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDialog;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDialogLayout;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Mensaje {


    public Object mensaje( @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") TableView table, StackPane Stack) {
        ObservableList<?> items = table.getItems();
        if(items.isEmpty()) {
                Text cabecera = new Text();
                cabecera.setText("NOTIFICACION");
                cabecera.setStyle("-fx-fill:red;-fx-font-weight:bold");
                Text mensaje= new Text();
                mensaje.setText("DATOS NO ENCONTRADOS");
                mensaje.setStyle("-fx-fill:black;-fx-font-weight:bold");
                JFXDialogLayout contenido = new JFXDialogLayout();
                contenido.setHeading((cabecera));
                contenido.setBody(mensaje);
                contenido.setStyle(" -fx-background-color:  linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, rgb(153,204,153) 0.0, rgb(153,204,153) 100.0);");
                JFXDialog dialogo = new JFXDialog(Stack,contenido, JFXDialog.DialogTransition.CENTER);
                JFXButton cerrar = new JFXButton("CERRAR");
                cerrar.setStyle(" -fx-background-color: white;-fx-border-color:  linear-gradient(to bottom, red 14%, red 91%); -fx-border-radius:  15%; -fx-text-fill: red;  -fx-font-family: 'Oswald Regular';-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-border-width: 5px;-fx-background:none;-fx-border-insets: -5.8;");
                cerrar.setOnAction(e3->{
                dialogo.close();
                });
                contenido.setActions(cerrar);
                dialogo.show(); 
        }
        return items;

    }
}
```

Comment: same comment as to most of the other answers: the question was about using BooleanBinding with lists emptyness - so this is not an answer to the question ;) And don't post several answers that are essentially the same ...

Comment: @kleopatra, you need to be more friendly, for this kind of sites, the expections for people in search for aswers, that  the programmers read daily in this sites are very high, maybe i am not the best yet, but i do something giving a little hope, don't be in the gray area, that's bad area, the kindness of human being is the accuarecy of humanity, and that is the area we need to be.

Comment: actually, I don't _need_ to do nor be anything that you deem important - and this is the last I willl say in that matter

Comment: as to the content: you still didn't delete the other answer (which is quite as wrong as this one because both simply don't answer the question) thus adding white noise to the site: that's unkind to future readers of this QA because they waste time in reading what most probably is not useful for them, it's just random code .. Really really don't understand why you choose to expand on the other incorrect answers (which have the same comment by me) - when you could have improved the accepted answer by making it robust against null ;)

Answer (score -1):

You Can Try this:

```
public Object mensaje(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") TableView table) {
    ObservableList<?> items = table.getItems();
    if(items.isEmpty()) {
            Text cabecera = new Text();
            cabecera.setText("NOTIFICACION");
            cabecera.setStyle("-fx-fill:red;-fx-font-weight:bold");
            Text mensaje= new Text();
            mensaje.setText("DATOS NO ENCONTRADOS");
            mensaje.setStyle("-fx-fill:black;-fx-font-weight:bold");
            JFXDialogLayout contenido = new JFXDialogLayout();
            contenido.setHeading((cabecera));
            contenido.setBody(mensaje);
            contenido.setStyle(" -fx-background-color:  linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, rgb(153,204,153) 0.0, rgb(153,204,153) 100.0);");
            JFXDialog dialogo = new JFXDialog(stackpaneitems,contenido, JFXDialog.DialogTransition.CENTER);
            JFXButton cerrar = new JFXButton("CERRAR");
            cerrar.setStyle(" -fx-background-color: white;-fx-border-color:  linear-gradient(to bottom, red 14%, red 91%); -fx-border-radius:  15%; -fx-text-fill: red;  -fx-font-family: 'Oswald Regular';-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-border-width: 5px;-fx-background:none;-fx-border-insets: -5.8;");
            cerrar.setOnAction(e3->{
            dialogo.close();
            });
            contenido.setActions(cerrar);
            dialogo.show(); 
    }
    return items;

}
```